# Windows Search w/PHP

Tags: php, ado, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-search

I have a basic PHP script to query the index using Windows Search that recently stopped functioning.

The script returns results from the index--so that much still works--but a fatal error occurs when the script apparently fails to recognize it should stop looping through the recordset.  Here's a PHP log excerpt in which you can see that results are found and returned and then the script dies:

> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York]
> Copyofguidance.58de8e890c10e.xlsx
>
> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York]
> SRFWebsiteSchedule.5876a0ab683a8.xlsx
>
> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York]
> CSI_D01_S04_T03_STEP.5877ad8385974.pdf
>
> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York]
> Copyofguidance.58cbf217868d9.xlsx
>
> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York]
> Copyofguidance.58cbf39ca3955.xlsx
>
> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York]
> Copyofguidance.58cbf565194fc.xlsx
>
> [11-Jul-2017 09:55:13 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:**
> Unknown
> **Description:** Unspecified error' in
> C:\WEB\srf\scripts\windowsSearch.php:149 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 C:\WEB\srf\scripts\windowsSearch.php(149): com->moveNext()
>
> ## 1 {main}   thrown in C:\WEB\srf\scripts\windowsSearch.php on line 149

And here are the relevant lines of code:

```
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$rs = new COM('ADODB.Recordset');

$provider = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended "
        . "Properties='Application=Windows';";
$conn->open($provider);
$str = "SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified FROM SYSTEMINDEX "
        . "WHERE DIRECTORY='" 
        . $nPath . "' AND CONTAINS('\"" 
        . $kw . "\"')";     
    $rs->cursorLocation = 3;
    $rs->lockType = 1;
    $rs->cursorType = 3;
    $rs->activeConnection = $conn;
    $rs->open($str);
if (!($rs->bof && $rs->eof)) {  
    $rs->moveFirst();
    while (!$rs->eof) { 
        error_log($rs->Fields['System.ItemName']->value);
        $rs->moveNext();
    }
}
```

I've noticed that the recordCount method throws a fatal error as well.  I'm not sure what could have changed to cause this issue, or whether or not there is another method that could be used as a workaround.

Other code using ADO continues to run without problem, although that code connects to SQL Server, not Windows Search.

The Windows 2008 R2 server receives regular patches and PHP was recently updated to 5.6.30.  Downgrading isn't really an option, even if that turned out to be the issue...

If I've left out any useful information, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Seems like the exception is thrown in moveNext(). You could try to wrap it in a try/catch block and catch and handle the thrown exception.

Comment: @BojanBedrač I was able to catch and ignore the error and the script will finish.  It would be nice to know what happened to necessitate this workaround, but it's a workaround that works for me, and that's good for now.  Thanks!  I'll leave this open for a little while to see if anyone has any insight into the moveNext() issue.